# How does $\frac{4{\pi}x +\cos(4{\pi}x)\sin(4{\pi}x)}{8{\pi}}+C$ become $\frac{\sin(8{\pi}x)+8{\pi}x}{16{\pi}}+C$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have an integral like

$$\frac{1}{4\pi}\int \cos^{2}(u)du$$

Where

$$u = 4{\pi}x$$

I get a result of $$\frac{4{\pi}x + \cos(4{\pi}x)\sin(4{\pi}x)}{8{\pi}} + C$$

But there is a further simplification for this that results in

$$\frac{\sin(8{\pi}x) + 8{\pi}x}{16{\pi}} + C$$

Can anyone go through each step to get from my result to the simplified result and list any concepts that are used, such as any trig identities, to find this simplification? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use trig identities.
$$\cos(x) \cdot \sin(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sin(2x)$$
so then you get:
$$\frac{\frac{\sin(8 \pi x)}{2} + 4 \pi x}{8\pi} + C$$
which simplifies to:
$$\frac{\sin(8\pi x) + 8\pi x}{16\pi} + C$$

Comment: Oops, it seems that someone else already posted the same idea while I was latexing. Sorry!

Comment: Appreciate it @Han Xiong thanks for providing the steps as well :)

Answer (score 1):

They have simply used the identity $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$ and solved it further

Comment: Thanks @thedumbkid, and this is one of the double angle identities, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @thedumbkid for providing the needed identity and @Han Xiong for the steps to implement it and get to the simplified form.

Needed Double Angle Identity:  $$2sin(x)cos(x) = sin(2x)$$
Steps to simplify: Follow @Han Xiong's answer

Thanks everyone :)